# How to remove time from <lightning:formattedDateTime>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a json coming from api and it has a datetime as 2019-01-01T00:00:00-05:00
I am displaying this in lightning component as `<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!medicareValues.effectivePeriod.datetimeBegin}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"/>`. But I want to remove the time and display the date as 2019-01-01. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: you can try `format()` function of `Date` apex class

Comment: @sfdc_sk, cud u let me know how in lightning component we can do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Datetime to Date conversion function in lightning, but there is an easy solution server side; add a "dateBegin" to your effectivePeriod object that is the date component of your date time then use that in your formattedDateTime call instead. This might ultimately come from a formula field using the DATEVALUE formula function against the datetimeBegin value's field.